# Is it possible that a form does not recognize values entered through selenium automation

Tags: javascript, selenium, validation, ui-automation

Another queer incident with web automation, I am developing automation for a asp.net/javascript based website. I have used the selenium IDE for firefox to fill in the values of a form and I can see the text in the required input fields. But the form validation fails complaining that the required fields are missing.

If I go the text fields manually and press tabs(with the same text) the form validation passed. My question: is it possible to write javascript code that ignore automatically filled values? If yes, how can I overcome this restriction.

Currently, assume that I have no source code access that does form validation. I can provide sample code if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, this behavior is possible when the form validator marks a field as validated only if there is a tab out. Though I don't like it but that's how the UI is designed.

To make the automation working in selenium IDE I used fireevent(locator,"blur")